# PHP Session cookie getting set with wrong path or random path

Tags: php, http, session, cookies

I am setting a PHP session cookie in my application. On some requests to the page in question, the PHP session cookie path is `\`, but on other requests to the same page, it gets set to the path of the page `\test\hello`.

I need it to always be set to `\`.

Why would it randomly change? How to I force it to always be `\`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `session_set_cookie_params` http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php to change path to `/`